# Java get Long larger than 1000000000

Tags: java

in this simple code i can not get Long larger than `1000000000`. lenght of that is 10 char and i want to get larger than such as 15 character.

```
long value = nextLong(rand,1000000000);

long nextLong(Random rng, long n) {
    long bits, val;
    do {
        bits = (rng.nextLong() << 1) >>> 1;
        val = bits % n;
    } while (bits-val+(n-1) < 0L);
    return val;
}
```

Comment: I think you need to use BigInt, see: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html

Comment: The size of the number should be fine.  I'm curious as to what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your `long` constant is missing an `L` suffix:

```
long value = nextLong(rand,100000000000000L);
```

> I want to get larger than such as 15 character.

Java's `long` has range of –9223372036854775808 to 9223372036854775807 (18 full digits + top digit in the range 0..8), which is sufficient to cover the range that you need to cover. If you need 19 decimal digits or more, you would need to use `BigInteger`.

Comment: The number is sufficiently small enough to be represented as an int.  I'm not sure that's what's going on here.

Comment: @Makoto I think OP is pretty explicit about it: he says he can get 10 digits (as shown in the example), but he wants 15 digits.

Comment: Yet nowhere in that method is he using something that supports less than 15 digits.  He's even passing it in as a int, which does get promoted to a long.  I'm not sure why the data type is in question here when there's something unusual going on with the bit shifts.  Or the modulo operation.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use BigInt.

Import using:

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
```

declare like this:

```
BigInteger myBigInt = new BigInteger("123456789123456789");
```

Comment: The number is sufficiently small enough to be represented as an int.  There's something else going on here.

Answer (score 0):

Increase your limit value of 'n'.  Since you are limiting the generated random value by performing a modulo 'n', obviously the generated value needs to be less than 'n'.  Since your limit is a long, you can increase that limit to allow for 15 digit results without other changes.

However I am not sure what you are trying to accomplish with the loop in the nextLong function.  It will only loop when bits > ( Long.MAX - n + 1 ).

Answer (score 0):

I get the feeling that you're limiting yourself by your own modulo operation.

Remember that modulo division is the same as short division - the kind we used back in third grade.  That is, instead of dividing out the entire number, we take the whole portion and the remainder.

So, let's take a simple example (a power of 10, since you're using one as well):

```
99 / 10 = 9 remainder 9
```

That is to say, if I divide 99 into 10 using short division, I will be able to divide it evenly 9 times, with 9 bits left over.  Notice that the left-over is an order of magnitude shorter of what I'm dividing into.

This scales up with higher orders of divisors:

```
999 / 10 = 99 remainder 9
9999 / 10 = 999 remainder 9
99999 / 10 = 9999 remainder 9
```

...and so forth.  Notice that our remainder is *always* an order of magnitude below our dividend.  This makes sense, since if it were larger than our dividend, it'd be another value we could add to the quotient, and not the remainder.

Now, we come back to your example.  You're taking a long value, which can be several orders of magnitude larger or smaller than your passed in value of a billion (which fits fine into an `int`, and is promoted to a `long` when you call your method).

The ultimate issue comes down to this:

```
val = bits % n;
```

...where `bits` is some arbitrary `long` value that *could* be greater than `n`.

Remember what we discovered above with the short division above?  That's right - your resulting `val` will be an order of magnitude below your `n` value - that is to say, it will *never* be larger than or equal to `n`.

I'm not entirely sure what it is you're trying to accomplish, so I don't have The Right Thing™ for you to do.  But I'd recommend that you re-evaluate the purpose of that modulo operation.